# Removing C/C++ style comments using boost::regex

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

I'm attempting to remove C and C++ style comments from a string using a regular expression.  I have found one for Perl that seems to do both:

`s#/\*[^*]*\*+([^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|//([^\\]|[^\n][\n]?)*?\n|("(\\.|[^"\\])*"|'(\\.|[^'\\])*'|.[^/"'\\]*)#defined $3 ? $3 : ""#gse;`

But I am unsure as to how to use this with a `boost::regex` code block, or what I need to do to transform it into a regular expression accepted by `boost::regex`.

FYI: I found the regular expression here: [perlfaq6](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-use-a-regular-expression-to-strip-C-style-comments-from-a-file?) and it seems to cover any case I would need.

I would prefer not to use `boost::spirit::qi` to do this, as it would add a great deal of time to compilation for the project.

EDIT:

```
std::string input = "hello /* world */ world";

boost::regex reg("(/\\*([^*]|(\\*+[^*/]))*\\*+/)|(//.*)");

input = boost::regex_replace(input, reg, "");
```

So the shorter regex does indeed work, however the longer one does not.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to understand and maintain this by using two separate regexes? First, get rid of /* ... */ then get rid of // ... eol.

Comment: @jmucchiello can't; they affect each other.

Comment: The regular expression should work with Boost's regular expressions pretty much the same way it does with perl. Just create a `boost::regex` object and apply it to a `std::string` using `boost::regex_match()` or `boost::regex_search()` to get a `boost::smatch`. What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: The format of the regular expression. I don't know if it will work exactly like that right out of the box.

Comment: @smparkes: Why on earth would one affect the other. Do /**/ first than // 2nd...

Comment: Also op. Why on earth would you do this? And why are you doing it in C++? -2 plz (note downvote, programming points :(. This is too weird)

Comment: Is the string you're modifying actually C or C++? If so I anticipate that you will not be able to make a regex that correctly matches comments the way a C or C++ parser will.

Comment: @nerozehl: did you give it a try? If you are unsure, think about what the regular expression does and see if the components map 1-to-1 to Boost's notation. Also, Boost supports Perl regular expressions. What is your concrete problem? What failed? What code did you try?

Comment: Why don't you use the preprocessor to do this? `gcc -E`, etc...

Comment: Boost.Regex is not capable of this; [Boost.Xpressive](http://www.boost.org/libs/xpressive/) is.

Comment: I'm stripping comments from a non C++ file that I would like to have comments in it that are in C/C++ format.

Comment: @acidzombie24: Of course they can interact.  You can comment out a `/*` or a `*/` by using a `//`.

Comment: @acidzombie24 e.g., `// /* \n a = 10; /*  */`

Comment: @OliCharlesworth can't really comment out a `*/`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I think you're right. I never ever seen a ///*. Although i have seen a //*/ but // is always ignore bc of the /* earlier in the file. +1 on your comment

Comment: @smparkes, the issue of // /* is part of the regex for doing /* */ first. But that doesn't change the fact that doing them separately is probably easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

It seems a bit strange that you would use a regex for this when boost already has a C++ preprocessor library ([Boost.Wave](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/wave/index.html)) which can be used to strip comments.

```
std::string strip_comments(std::string const& input) {
    std::string output;
    typedef boost::wave::cpplexer::lex_token<> token_type;
    typedef boost::wave::cpplexer::lex_iterator<token_type> lexer_type;
    typedef token_type::position_type position_type;

    position_type pos;

    lexer_type it = lexer_type(input.begin(), input.end(), pos, 
        boost::wave::language_support(
            boost::wave::support_cpp|boost::wave::support_option_long_long));
    lexer_type end = lexer_type();

    for (;it != end; ++it) {
        if (*it != boost::wave::T_CCOMMENT
         && *it != boost::wave::T_CPPCOMMENT) {
            output += std::string(it->get_value().begin(), it->get_value().end());
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if

```
\*
```

becomes

```
\\*
```

then why doesn't

```
[^\\]
```

become

```
[^\\\\]
```